# MySQL performance problems for a simple select query

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

Have a MySQL performance problem that I don't get.

This query most often takes ~1 second to execute, but sometimes it takes 5+ minutes.

```
SELECT  sb.id AS id, sb.name AS name,
ROUND(sb.dkprice / 100, 0) AS price, bs.name AS shopname, country
    FROM  shopbikes sb, categoriesshopbikes csb, shops s
    WHERE  sb.id = csb.`shopbikeid`
      AND  csb.categoryid = 93
      AND  sb.brand = 'Ghost'
      AND  dkprice > 0
      AND  sb.dkprice IS NOT NULL
      AND  sb.`shopid` = s.id
    ORDER BY  dkprice
    LIMIT  1
```

There are sometimes 5-8 of these queries running at the same time, for different brands.

When I execute SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST, I can see a number of these queries are running and some of them have been running for a long time (up to several minutes).

The tables in the query all have indexes for all the relevant columns (i.e. the ones that the tables are matched by).

Size of the tables:

- shopbikes = 600,000 rows
- categoriesshopbikes = 100,000 rows
- shops = 100 rows

Any idea what is going wrong and how I can fix it?

---

Update: I have converted the query to an explicit join:

```
SELECT  sb.id AS id, sb.name AS NAME,
ROUND(sb.dkprice / 100, 0) AS price, s.name AS shopname, country
    FROM  shopbikes sb
    JOIN  categoriesshopbikes csb  ON (sb.id = csb.shopbikeid)
    JOIN  shops s  ON (sb.shopid = s.id)
    WHERE  csb.`categoryid` = 93
      AND  sb.`brand` = 'Cannondale'
      AND  dkprice > 0
      AND  dkprice IS NOT NULL
    ORDER BY  dkprice
    LIMIT  1
```

It didn't help. The query still often takes a long time to execute.

---

Explain output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xilvV.png

Comment: Side note: explicit join syntax (aka ANSI join) has been around for many years (and probably MySQL supports it from the beginning). I suggest you try it since it makes query way more readable.

Comment: Please, post those slow queries which are listed in `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST` output.

Comment: Where's the output of `EXPLAIN`? Which storage engine are we talking about? Is your MySQL tuned so it can utilize server resources properly? You need to provide the output of `EXPLAIN` (if you don't know what it is, check similar mysql questions), which storage engine you're using, output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table in question and your MySQL configuration. After that, we'll have enough info to determine what the bottleneck is and how to sort it out.

Comment: Concerning SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST, the output is currently 5 x these queries. All in state "Sending data" with time 534, 331, 317, 374 and 28

Rows_sent, rows_examined and rows_read for all the queries are 0.

Comment: Output from explain: http://i.imgur.com/kfMPBrd.png

Comment: If you single thread the query does it exhibit the same behavior as when multi-threaded?

Comment: @P.Salmon 1) you can't "tell" mysql to multithread something. 2) multithreading does not improve I/O of your hard disk. 3) adding threads to an I/O problem doesn't make I/O faster.

Comment: @Mjh Does this not work then https://www.percona.com/blog/2014/01/07/increasing-slow-query-performance-with-parallel-query-execution/?

Comment: I can't tell which columns are in which tables.  Please qualify all columns, and provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: Thanks for converting to `JOIN..ON`; it is easier to read.  True, it will not change performance any.

Comment: @P.Salmon you're quoting things out of context. The text tells you that there are queries that fit this model and especially the ones whose data is sharded. The issue here is clear, MySQL scans ~450k rows, disk is slow so it doesn't deliver it on time and CPU probably doesn't do a lot of work overall since that's not a lot of data. This is easily solved by increasing `innodb_buffer_pool_size`, shifting I/O to RAM.

Comment: `innodb_buffer_pool_size` should be about 70% of _available_ RAM (if you have at least 4GB of RAM).  That _may_ change this from an I/O-bound problem into a CPU-bound problem.  (It would be helpful to know which case you have now.)

Comment: It's a VPS with 1 GB ram. I currently have innodb_buffer_pool_size = 136314880 Should I change it?

Comment: @Louisa - `136314880 `  is ~136MB so you should change it. However, to *what* value - you need to check what's the actual available RAM on your VPS so you don't allocate more than you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`csb` needs `INDEX(shopbikeid, category_id)` in either order.  If `categoriesshopbikes` is a many-to-many mapping table, did you follow all the recommendations [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table)?

`sb` needs `INDEX(brand, dkprice)`, in that order.

I think `AND  dkprice IS NOT NULL` is redundant with `AND  dkprice > 0`.

Comment: Adding the indexes you mention seems to have fixed the problem.

Comment: Works perfectly now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
FROM shopbikes sb, categoriesshopbikes csb, shops s
```

I'd have to look at the query plan, but I think this line is the problem. This kind of `FROM` clause will probably create a cartesian product from the listed tables (i. e. 600k * 100k * 100 rows).

I'm guessing that proper `JOIN` clauses will help

```
FROM shopbikes sb JOIN categoriesshopbikes csb ON (sb.id = csb.shopbikeid) JOIN shops s ON (sb.shopid = s.id)
```

Comment: Thanks. I have edited the query as shown in the update above. It didn't improve the performance.